# Disable directrory listing

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a folder named import at my root directory where the public folder resides. In the import folder i have lots of sub folders and each sub folder contain images and pdf files. when a user directly access the import folder through url like

```
   www.mysite.com/import/subfolder/image.jpg
```

The image opens in the browser but when he trys to open any pdf file he is not allowed to open the pdf.

Now when he access the following in url he can see the whole directory structure

```
www.mysite.com/import/subfolder
```

Now he can only see all the images in the subfolder with above url

```
 www.mysite.com/import/
```

with this one he can see all the folders in import The good thing is he can only see images in the folders not the pdfs.

Is it possible that I somehow disable this listing of directory as well?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this line to .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

That will disable indexes.

Comment: This is implied by `.htaccess`, anyway just a note for anyone who might not know - this works for Apache web-server only

Comment: @galymzhan The OP tagged the question with `.htaccess`, which implies he's using apache.

Comment: @AleksG  there are bunch of web servers that support `.htaccess`

Comment: @Death true, although most of those that call the file `.htaccess` are derivatives from apache.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent directory listings, create a .htaccess file which includes the following text:

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the directory listing on a per-directory level in .htaccess using `Options -Indexes` in the `Directory`, for example:

```
<Directory /absolute/path/to/www.mysite.com/import/>
    ...
    Options -Indexes
    ...
</Directory>
```

This way you can disable directory listing for one directory, but still allow it for another.